# Request["key"] is not working in C# web application (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, web, request, http-post

I am trying to get parameter form a View and passing it to the controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public string GetWord()
 {
     string word = Request["word"];
     return word;
 }
```

But I got an error

> Indexing using the [] construct cannot be used for an Http Request expression

I looked at documentation and I don't know why it is not working. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Is "word" a query parameter, a part of the body or coming from some other part of the request?

Comment: I have it in my Index.cshtml:

Comment: <input type="text" name="word" />

Comment: And I have: @using (Html.BeginForm("GetWord", "Home"))

Comment: And which version of .net is this? .net core or .net framework

Comment: It is .Net Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use more specific property to get the value, instead of Request["word"], depends where the "word" key is:

1. In query string -> `Request.QueryString["word"]`;
2. In ServerVariables -> `Request.ServerVariables["word"]`;
3. In Params -> `Request.Params["word"]`;
4. In Form -> `Request.Form["word"]`;
5. In Cookies -> `Request.Cookies["word"]`;
6. In Headers -> `Request.Headers["word"]`;

In your case, you could use the 4th one: `Request.Form["word"]`, but please make sure the `<input>` control is included in the `BeginFrom` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding a parameter to the form

```
 [HttpPost]
 public string GetWord([FromForm]string word)
 {
     var postedWord = word;
     return postedWord;
 }
```

As your form gets more complex you might like to create a class and bind the submitted form to that

```
 public string GetWord([FromForm]MyFormModel formData)
```